# creating simple states for a stateless input

Tags: data-structures, user-interface, io

Given an input device (basically a keyboard) that reports keyup and keydown, how may I most efficiently store and retrieve information about *which keys are currently depressed*? My first thought was a dynamic array, but maintaining and searching a dynamic array seems like a serious drain on resources.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Joe

Comment: Why would that be a major drain on resources?

Comment: You can use bit flags easily enough for this and it would be very fast to determine what buttons are depressed.

Comment: sorry, bit flags?

Comment: john: well, an array of undefined length + searching it every time to see if a particular button is depressed seems like a good way to waste resources and slow down the program. Maybe I'm not understanding something correctly (always a possibility :)).

Comment: @jamesson Sorry, here is an interesting explanation for C++ but they exists for any major language. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1590/ . I will try to write up a nice explanation as an answer if I can in a bit (or anyone else) but I think this is a great solution for you. I have used bit flags for enumerating input types on embedded devices a fair bit as they are fast and memory efficient.

Comment: Are you talking about an embedded system with a few kB of RAM? If not, why do you care how much memory a `HashSet<Key> _pressedKeys` takes? It's negligible. Or just use an array. Typically there are very few keys pressed at the same time, so a linear algorithm should be fine.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, experimentation seems to support the notion that a dynamic array is tolerable here. Will continue along that route until a better option presents itself

Answer (score 1):

A fixed-length array will work just fine, since the number of keys can't change.
So, make an array, call it *depressed*, of length N, where N is the number of keys on your input device.
When key X is depressed, set depressed[X] to True.
When key X is released, set depressed[X] to False.
To report the True/False state of any given key, you'll need a mapping from user-/API-level names, to indices into your array.
e.g. MOTOR_REVERSE_TOGGLE -> position 6 in your array.

As for *efficiency*, an array should be adequate for space, unless you've got very tight memory restrictions on whatever device you're programming. In that case, you'd use a bitfield to store the data. Basically, it's the same as your array, except instead of words being set to True or False (which would end up a some magic numbers, say for example 11111111 and 00000000), you set individual bits in a word to 1 or 0.